# PHP replace : find and replace the same characters with different text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

How can I find and replace the same characters in a string with two different characters? I.E. The first occurrence with one character, and the second one with another character, for the entire string in one go?

This is what I'm trying to do (so users need not type html in the body): I've used preg_replace here, but I'll willing to use anything else.

```
$str = $str = '>>Hello, this is code>> Here is some text >>This is more code>>';

$str = preg_replace('#[>>]+#','[code]',$str);

echo $str;

//output from the above
//[code]Hello, this is code[code] Here is some text [code]This is more code[code]

//expected output
//[code]Hello, this is code[/code] Here is some text [code]This is more code[/code]
```

But problem here is, both `>>` get replaced with `[code]`. Is it possible to somehow replace the first `>>` with `[code]` and the second `>>` with a `[/code]` for the entire output?

Does php have something to do this in one go? How can this be done?

Comment: Why not use `>>` for `[code]` and `<<` as `[/code]` ? How shell be replaced third `>>`?

Comment: @Justinas To make it easy for newbie users to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '>>Hello, this is code>> Here is some text >>This is more code>>';
echo preg_replace( "#>>([^>]+)>>#", "[code]$1[/code]", $str );
```

---

The above will fail if something like the following is your input:

```
>>Here is code >to break >stuff>>
```

To deal with this, use negative lookahead:

```
#>>((?!>[^>]).+?)>>#
```

will be your pattern.

```
echo preg_replace( "#>>((?!>[^>]).+?)>>#", "[code]$1[/code]", $str );
```

Comment: You're correct. And your second pattern handles that very well. I happened to be testing after you posted your answer, but never thought of a user putting in `>` between the `>>` string.

Comment: Can you please help me with one small thing - how can I add something that will do a replace only if there are 2 `>>` and not more or less. Ex: `$str = '>>Hello, this is code>> Here is some text >>>This is more code>>>.'; echo preg_replace( "#>>{2}((?!>[^>]).+?)>>{2}#", "[code]$1[/code]", $str );` Only replace strings with `>>` not `>>>`. I added a {2} which I thought should work, but does not work.